# Linking not successful upon compiling a dummy C++ program

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have this file: `myfuncts.hpp`:

```
#ifndef FUNCTS_
#define FUNCTS_
namespace root {
namespace functs {
template <typename T>
class f1 {
public:
  T r;
  f1();
};
}
}
#endif
```

I have the implementation: `myfuncts.cpp`:

```
#include "myfuncts.hpp"
template <typename T>
root::functs::f1<T>::f1() { /* do somethng */ }
```

Then I have my main routine:

```
#include "impulses.hpp"
int main(int argc, char** argv);
int main(it argc, char** argv) {
  root::functs::f1<double> f();
}
```

I compile it:

```
g++ main.cpp functs.cpp
```

And got this:

> /tmp/ccrdJEQt.o: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined
>   reference to`root::functs::f1::f1()' collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to read about [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), because when you do

```
root::functs::f1<double> f();
```

you declare `f` to be a function which returns a `root::functs::f1<double>` object.

You might also want to read [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), as to why you actually get the `undefined reference` error. It's because the header file doesn't fully define the class. For templated classes, the complete implementation have to be in the header file as well.

Comment: How can I be so stupid... you're right!!! I remember my god... Thanks a lot, of course the header gotta go there...